# Sass have no effects using webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, ecmascript-6, webpack

So i use web pack, new to this, here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "postronix",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.24.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.13.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        path: './bin',
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [

    ]
}
```

file.scss

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

ul {

  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
  background-color: #282828;
}
```

app.js:

```
 var css = require("!css!sass!./file.scss");
 import 'babel-polyfill';
 import cats from './cats';
 import $ from 'jquery';

 $('<h1>Cats</h1>').appendTo('body');
 const ul = $('<ul></ul>').appendTo('body');
 for (const cat of cats) {
     $('<li></li>').text(cat).appendTo(ul);
 }
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
     </head>
     <body>
         <script src="bin/app.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

after execute "webpack" in cli, it was not showing any errors,
chrome console not find any error too. but why scss not affected, colors don't change, font don't change.

btw i found this code inside "transpiled" js, app.bundle.js:

```
exports.push([module.id, "ul {\n  font: 100% Helvetica, sans-serif;\n  color: #333;\n  background-color: #282828; }\n", ""]);
```

please help

Comment: Try just calling 'require' without assigning it to the css variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using two loader configurations to handle SASS files:

- the one in `webpack.config.js` (`loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]`)
- one in the JS file: `require("!css!sass!./file.scss")`

The latter seems to take precedence, but doesn't include the `style` loader, which is the one that inserts a `<style>` element into your HTML. Without it, you need to somehow manually inject the styles into the HTML.

The simplest solution is to just use `require('./file.scss')`

More information [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html).